# Making Mulberry Cider

Tags: cider

Has a mulberry cider been made? I have a mulberry tree that has so much fruit every year and was wondering how I would go about trying that? I've only just bottled my very first batch of beer....so very new to this!

Answer (score 1):

It might take a huge amount of fruit to make a substantial batch of say 5 gallons.  I would be more tempted to create a mulberry flavored cider with apple cider as my base.  You can find cider that hasn't been treated with any preservatives fairly easily.  They have yeasts designed for cider or I've used champagne yeast with good results. As popular as cider has become there should be a multitude of recipes out there.

Comment: What do you reckon is a huge amount?

Comment: 4lb of fruit per gallon of wine, from this recipe: https://www.homebrewit.com/mulberry-wine-recipes/